# Not able to create database in pgadmin

Tags: sql, django, postgresql, pgadmin-4

i am new to PostgresSQL and i am figuring out on how to create the database in pgadmin. I have ubuntu 20.04 running and it has postgresSQL.

[The snap of my pgadmin panel is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rh138.png)

Update:
So, if anybody having the same doubt, here the steps :

1. Go to your terminal and use sudo -u postgres psql to enter into the
   postgres command line.
2. Then create the database using

   CREATE
   DATABASE databasename;

then create the user using

```
CREATE USER
    userame WITH PASSWORD 'password';
```

then grant the permission and
connect the database with the created user

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON
    DATABASE databasename TO username;
```

After this, go to your pgAdmin
and then create the new server.give your name to your server. go the connection tab , enter
localhost as your hostname. Edit the username and password which you
have created above in command line and save the server.

3. Done.

Comment: Documentation is available at https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/development/database_dialog.html

Comment: Video tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lG2Nes-wi54

Comment: Now you don't want to add ssh, ssl .But add your current database to maintanance database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a new install of PgAdmin. Your first task then is to define the connections to your database.  <br./>

1. In the Left panel right click on Servers.
2. Click click the Create Server
3. In resulting dialog enter a User defined name for the connection.
4. Click the Connection tab.
5. Complete the connection information as necessary (see [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5fzUf.jpg))
6. Complete SSH, SSL, Advanced tabs as needed (you may need to contact
   your DBA).
7. Save and exit pgAdmin (exit may not be necessary, but I always do).
8. Restart pgAdmin.
9. Again Left panel, click the **>** to expand the list of connections.
10. Double Click the desired database.

Answer (score 1):

The first time I tried to run Postgres with Django, I followed the instructions in [this article](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-postgresql-with-your-django-application-on-ubuntu-16-04) and I don't think I could've explained this any better.

If you're still stuck on how to initialize the database, there is another article linked under the "Prerequisites" section that gives you an idea of how to get Postgres running.

Since you didn't mention what methods you tried, this is the best help I can relate.