# pgadmin has no option to create server

Tags: pgadmin-4

I installed postgresql 14 that came with pgadmin on my new windows 11 computer. I created a server group, called "Unicorn Here". I am trying to "Create Server" by right clicking the left pane and the option isn't available for me.

Also, not sure if this piece of info is useful, but I had to add the postgreSQL 14 bin path to my environmental variables to access psql shell.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1JcFt.png)

You'll notice there is a server there called test-unicorn. The only way I was able to create this option was by following the steps from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62915202/not-able-to-create-database-in-pgadmin)

Please let me know if there is any other info I should add.

Comment: They renamed "Create server" to the much better "Register server" which reflects what this does (because the old one didn't really "create" a server)